# Clearing a DataGridView which was populated from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

Right now I have a table set up that will populate based on the searched authors last name. I want only one author to show up at a time but this current code doesn't remove the previous search result, instead it adds the next search result below the first. It seems like I need to clear the datagridview or bindingsource however I've had no luck with that. 
I tried utilizing

```
datagridview.DataSource = null;
bindingsource.DataSource = null;
bindingsource.Clear();
```

in different ways before the if statement in my code with the idea that the table would be cleared before adding the next search result. What happens though is it just clears all my data after a few clicks of the button and then it won't display anything until I restart the program. I am very new to this and I've been trying to get a hang of it but it's going slow.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {                  
      if (txtSearch.Text == " ")
          return;
      else
      {              
          dbcontext.Authors
              .Where(author => author.LastName.Equals(txtSearch.Text))
              .Load();

          authorBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.Authors.Local.ToBindingList();
      }
  }
```

Comment: how are you setting rows to datagridview : Rows.Add() or Datasource?

Comment: What's `dbcontext`? Maybe it's adding to `Authors.Local` every time you call `Load()`.

Comment: I'm using Datasource

Comment: dbcontext is a variable for my Entity Framework.  private BooksExamples.BooksEntities dbcontext =
         new BooksExamples.BooksEntities();

Comment: Yeah, Load() keeps adding the authors searched for but it won't clear the previous author before it adds the new so the new one ends up underneath the first one.

Comment: It seems like datagridview.DataSource = null; would be what I want but when I place that before the if statement nothing will show up in the table even if do a search. I must be thinking about it wrong.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the use of `Load` and `Local`. See my answer.

Comment: I might be, this stuff is confusing me terribly. I think I need it to add to Authors.Local with Load() for it to display in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj592911.aspx) method just ensures the entities are loaded [locally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj592872.aspx). It's basically a dummy method that just puts the query results into EF's cache.

You're currently ensuring that the search results are in the cache, then displaying the entire cache.

You don't need to explicitly load your entities, and you don't want to display *all* local entities, you only want the result of your search.

I think this would work:

```
authorBindingSource.DataSource = 
  dbcontext.Authors
    .Where(author => author.LastName.Equals(txtSearch.Text))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That actually gives me a couple errors.
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Author' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Matt\Documents\School Stuff\programming\ch22\ch22\BooksExamples\DisplayTable\DisplayAuthorsTable.cs 67 64 DisplayTable

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'BindingList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Matt\Documents\School Stuff\programming\ch22\ch22\BooksExamples\DisplayTable\DisplayAuthorsTable.cs 67 52 DisplayTable

Comment: If it doesn't work, try changing `ToBindingList` to just `ToList` - I don't think you actually need a binding list here.

Comment: That works exactly as I needed it to. Thanks for saving the rest of my hair, I about pulled it all out already. By the way I did have to change the ToBindingList to just ToList but then it worked perfectly. Thanks again man.

Comment: Awesome. I changed to `ToList` in my answer as well.